# No netdom.exe in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

It appears that netdom is no longer an available command. Has it been replaced? I would like to continue pragmatically setting computers up and need to know what to use for win10

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise is not released until tomorrow, the Home edition doesn't support domain joining

Comment: On Windows 7, you had to [install RSAT](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/29/use-powershell-to-replace-netdom-commands-to-join-the-domain.aspx) to get access to netdom.  But you can use `Add-Computer`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's domain join you're using netdom for: PowerShell has the add-computer cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install "Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10",you can download it from [this website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520).